# PowerShell DSC: xWebSite error : Desired website bindings are not valid for website

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc, azure-automation

Scenario : Trying to create a https website with DSC using Azure Automation Account. I get the below error. Did you face the same scenario? Any help will be great. 
HTTP bindings are working fine.

Windows 2012 R2

XWebAdministration Module version: 1.17.0.0

Error : PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_xWebsite  failed to execute Test-TargetResource functionality with error message: Desired website bindings are not valid for website

DSC Node Config:

```
foreach ($Site in $Node.Sites)
        {
            xWebSite "$($Site.Name)WebSite"
            {
                Ensure = "Present"
                Name = $Site.Name
                ApplicationPool = "$($Site.Name)"
                PhysicalPath = $Site.Path
                State = 'Started'
                DependsOn = "[xWebAppPool]$($Site.Name)AppPool"
                BindingInfo = MSFT_xWebBindingInformation
                    {
                        Protocol = 'https'
                        Port = $Site.Port
                        CertificateStoreName = 'MY'
                        CertificateThumbprint = $(Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My | where { $_.Subject -match "WMSvc" } | select -First 1).Thumbprint
                    } 
            }
```

DSC Configuration:

```
    $data = @{
        AllNodes = @(
            @{
                Sites = @(
                            @{Name="website1";Port="8643";Path="C:\inetpub\www\website1";Apps="App1","App2"},                            @{Name="website2";Port="9643";Path="C:\inetpub\www\website2";Apps="App3","App4"})
    })
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you only add one https site?

Comment: Still the same issue. Looks like xwebsite doesn't support get command at certificate thumbprint.if I enter the certificate thumbprint as a string it works fine..Basically we can't dynamically pass values..

Comment: You could set that as a variable higher up then pass it in as a string

Answer (score 1):

Expressions that are used outside of a script-resource in DSC-configurations are executed on compilation. The following line would be executed on the management computer, where there certificate probably doesn't exist and will set the thumbprint in the .mof-file to `NULL`. You can verify this by looking in the generated mof-file.

```
CertificateThumbprint = $(Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My | where { $_.Subject -match "WMSvc" } | select -First 1).Thumbprint
```

You need to specify the thumbprint as a string-value, or use a Script-resource to set the binding where you could run your `Get-ChildItem`-command as part of the SetScript-scriptblock.

Comment: Hey Frode, Thanks for your reply..I tried to do what you suggested but still the same issue.

Comment: GetScript = { }
            TestScript = { $False }
            SetScript = {
                  $certificatestore= $(Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My | where { $_.Subject -match "WMSvc" } | select -First 1)
                  write-host "This is $certificatestore"                      
                } 
        }  and in the bindinginfo I am trying this CertificateThumbprint = "$($certificatestore.Thumbprint)" ..but still the same issue..is this what you were suggesting? Error: Desired website bindings are not valid for website

Comment: No, add the binding using a appropriate cmdlet in setscript  (remember to set working testscript and getscript too). You can't set bindinginfo using xWebsite if you can't specify a static value for thumbprint AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped me understand that while I was trying to grab the Certificate Subject name with a Powershell query, it wouldn't resolve on the Node itself, and instead I used configuration data variables to build the string I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Realize this is old and fairly redundant to guidance, but basically you'd either have an imperative command pass the thumbprint into the DSC as a parameter or you could have your DSC imperatively call the server for the thumbprint during compilation like below (except my example reaches out by subject name incase there's dupes and gets the latest).

```
$tp = Invoke-Command -Session (New-PSSession -ComputerName $Node.NodeName -Credential $RunAs -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)) -ScriptBlock {
                                param ([string] $Certi)
                            (dir cert:LocalMachine -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Subject -like "*$Certi*" -Or $_.FriendlyName -like "*$Certi*"  } | sort $_.NotBefore | select -last 1).Thumbprint.ToString() 
                            } -ArgumentList $Name

                PfxImport $Name
                {
                    Thumbprint = $tp
                    Location   = "LocalMachine"
                    Store      = $Store
                    Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($RunAs.UserName, (ConvertTo-SecureString $CertPass -AsPlainText -Force))
                    Path       = $Pfx
                    Ensure     = $Ensure
                }
```